# Setting FOV in Maxscript

Tags: camera, rendering, maxscript

I am fairly new to Mascript and Autodesk - I have a simple script, that places a camera and I want to change the FOV, horizontally and vertically.

I am using the example provided from [Max-Script Documentation](http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2017/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_17350E60_DF84_4B3F_8A4D_772914FF2A1C_htm), and my script looks like the following:

```
rgb_cam = freecamera name: "foo"  position:[0,0,0]
rgb_cam.fov Float default: 45.0
```

The second command gives me the error:

```
-- Type error: Call needs function or class, got: 45.0
-- MAXScript callstack:
--  thread data: threadID:8848
--  ------------------------------------------------------
--  [stack level: 0]
--  In top-level
```

So I guess, that the way the function is called is wrong, however the documentation said so. 
Lastly, this will only change the horizontal fov, not the vertical one - how can I change it via MaxScript?

I am using Autodesk 3ds Max 2018 - Student Version

Answer (score 2):

You just have to assign the value to the fov parameter, you do this like this:

```
rgb_cam = freecamera name: "foo"  position:[0,0,0]
rgb_cam.fov = 33.0
```

What the documentation is telling you is that the fov defaults to 45 and is a float value, that line is not a valid piece of code.

Comment: Thank you, this solves the first part - however, how can I change the horizontal and vertical view of the camera?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution by myself. The documentation is not how to execute the files, but merely showing how the default parameters are. Furthermore, one has to change the flag determining the actual chosen field of view settings, like this:

```
rgb_cam = freecamera name: "rgb"  position:[0.0,0.0,25.0] rotation: (eulertoquat (eulerAngles 0 0 0))
--Horizontal FOV 
rgb_cam.fovType = 1
rgb_cam.fov = 84.1
--Vertical FOV
rgb_cam.fovType = 2
rgb_cam.fov = 48.1
```

Comment: The fovType property only changes how is the FOV displayed in the UI, setting .fov will change only the horizontal FOV value. To change the vertical FOV, change the render resolution accordingly.

Comment: Oh I see, just noticed that - however the resolution and the FOV are two different things.

Comment: The horizontal FOV is the parameter that drives the other parameters, changing the render resolution and by that changing the aspect ratio will give you the changed vertical FOV. See also the GetCamVFOV function in the help.

Comment: Sry, I can not quite follow you - how can I change the FOV so, that I have a resolution of 1920x1080 and a FOV of 84.1 x 53.8 for example?

Comment: Just set the FOV to 84.1 in that case, with this resolution, the vertical FOV will be 53.8. If there was a different vertical resolution, it would be different.

Comment: But I need the vertical FOV to be 48.1 , not 53.8 , My physical camera in the real world has this resolution (kinect v2) and fov

Comment: With that vertical FOV, the resolution would have to be 1920x950 (square pixels) or it'd have to be non-square pixels.

Comment: http://smeenk.com/kinect-field-of-view-comparison/ shows that the  Kinect V2 has "1920 x 1080 pixels and a fov of 84.1 x 53.8 resulting in an average of about 22 x 20 pixels per degree", so I guess that it has to be non-square pixels

Comment: 1920x1080 at 84.1x53.8 is perfectly square pixels (pixels per degree doesn't matter here, you get more pixels per degree the more to the edge, you can't average it like that). You said before that the vertical FOV is 48.1 which with a horizontal FOV at 84.1 wouldn't be square. Read the discussion once again, read the help entry, check wiki. You have the answer and there's no point in arguing any further.

Comment: sry was not arguing, I am just not familiar with this kind of topic very much. Sry about this misunderstand, i accidently transposed digits